# Angular xeditable, editable form nested in form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, razor, x-editable

I am currently working on MVC and Angular in an app, I just gave a try to Angular xeditable, but there is a problem that I can't put this form, which is needed to be able to edit, inside my wrapping form.
I am making a form so I can save user name, password, and other data, and also I want to save their phones, however, they can have several numbers, so this is why I want to use xeditable in the same form but because of my wrapping form, there is a conflict with xeditable-form and I have to take it off from the wrapping form to make it work.

This is basically the structure I am looking for

```
<MainForm> 
      --name--
      --lastname--

      --Phones--
      <table>
      <tr>
        <td>--editable field--</td>
        <td>--editable field--</td>
        <td> <form editable-form></form>
      </tr>
      </table>

 </MainForm>
```

But there is an error that does not let me do that and I have to take the editable form outside of the Main form to make it work. But I need it inside so I can post them to the database.
Is anyone familiar with this Angular xeditable that can give me a hand with this? don't know if it is possible

Answer (score 0):

same here and console showes

> Form with editable elements should have `editable-form` attribute

I put in the parent form the attribute and the error doen't showing but the table doesn't work.

i think there no way to do what we want unless divide the forms. In that case server side must edit too, so i think that is not the best way.

maybe using datatable or another plugin table